# Javers giving Duplicate key name 'jv_global_id_owner_id_fk_idx' when starting from Spring Boot with mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, javers

I'm trying to integrate Javers 5.9.0 with my Spring Boot 2.1.13 application with mySQL.

As soon I run my application I'm getting

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Duplicate key name 'jv_global_id_owner_id_fk_idx'

Please find the full error stack

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'JaversFromStarter' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/javers/spring/boot/sql/JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Duplicate key name 'jv_global_id_owner_id_fk_idx'     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]   at
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate key name
>   'jv_global_id_owner_id_fk_idx'    at
>   org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.executeSQL(JaversSchemaManager.java:165)
>   ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.9.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.addIndex(JaversSchemaManager.java:343)
>   ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.9.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.addDbIndexOnOwnerId(JaversSchemaManager.java:102)
>   ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.9.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.ensureSchema(JaversSchemaManager.java:61)
>   ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.9.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.javers.repository.sql.JaversSqlRepository.ensureSchema(JaversSqlRepository.java:186)
>   ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.9.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:186)
>   ~[javers-spring-jpa-5.9.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:36)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]    at
>   org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.ensureSchema(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:183)
>   ~[javers-spring-jpa-5.9.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.afterPropertiesSet(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:177)
>   ~[javers-spring-jpa-5.9.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1830)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]     ... 16 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate
>   key name 'jv_global_id_owner_id_fk_idx'   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]  at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]  at
>   org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.executeSQL(JaversSchemaManager.java:160)
>   ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.9.0.jar:na]    ... 27 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around

1. in application.yaml make following changes `sqlSchemaManagementEnabled: false`. This will stop creating tables at application start up
2. Create the table/indexes manually. Something like

> CREATE TABLE javers.jv_commit ( commit_pk BIGINT NOT NULL 
>   AUTO_INCREMENT, author VARCHAR(200), commit_date TIMESTAMP(3),
>   commit_date_instant VARCHAR(30), commit_id NUMERIC(22,2), CONSTRAINT
>   jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
>   CREATE INDEX jv_commit_commit_id_idx ON
>   gears_javers.jv_commit(commit_id)
>
> CREATE TABLE javers.jv_commit_property ( property_name
>   VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL, property_value VARCHAR(600), commit_fk BIGINT,
>   CONSTRAINT jv_commit_property_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_fk,
>   property_name), CONSTRAINT jv_commit_property_commit_fk FOREIGN
>   KEY(commit_fk) REFERENCES gears_javers.jv_commit(commit_pk) ) ENGINE =
>   InnoDB
>
> CREATE INDEX jv_commit_property_commit_fk_idx ON
>   gears_javers.jv_commit_property(commit_fk) CREATE INDEX
>   jv_commit_property_property_name_property_value_idx ON
>   gears_javers.jv_commit_property(property_name,property_value(191))
>
> CREATE TABLE javers.jv_global_id ( global_id_pk BIGINT NOT NULL 
>   AUTO_INCREMENT, local_id VARCHAR(191), fragment VARCHAR(200),
>   type_name VARCHAR(200), owner_id_fk BIGINT, CONSTRAINT jv_global_id_pk
>   PRIMARY KEY(global_id_pk), CONSTRAINT jv_global_id_owner_id_fk FOREIGN
>   KEY(owner_id_fk) REFERENCES gears_javers.jv_global_id(global_id_pk) )
>   ENGINE = InnoDB
>
> CREATE INDEX jv_global_id_local_id_idx ON
>   gears_javers.jv_global_id(local_id); CREATE INDEX
>   jv_global_id_owner_id_fk_idx ON
>   gears_javers.jv_global_id(owner_id_fk);
>
> CREATE TABLE javers.jv_snapshot ( snapshot_pk BIGINT NOT NULL 
>   AUTO_INCREMENT, type VARCHAR(200), version BIGINT, state TEXT,
>   changed_properties TEXT, managed_type VARCHAR(200), global_id_fk
>   BIGINT, commit_fk BIGINT, CONSTRAINT jv_snapshot_pk PRIMARY
>   KEY(snapshot_pk), CONSTRAINT jv_snapshot_global_id_fk FOREIGN
>   KEY(global_id_fk) REFERENCES gears_javers.jv_global_id(global_id_pk),
>   CONSTRAINT jv_snapshot_commit_fk FOREIGN KEY(commit_fk) REFERENCES
>   gears_javers.jv_commit(commit_pk) ) ENGINE = InnoDB
>
> CREATE INDEX jv_snapshot_global_id_fk_idx ON
>   gears_javers.jv_snapshot(global_id_fk); CREATE INDEX
>   jv_snapshot_commit_fk_idx ON gears_javers.jv_snapshot(commit_fk);
>   CREATE INDEX jv_snapshot_owner_id_fk_idx ON
>   gears_javers.jv_global_id(owner_id_fk);

Answer (score 0):

Try to reproduce the issue int this test https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-persistence-sql/src/test/groovy/org/javers/repository/sql/integration/docker/MySqlDockerIntegrationTest.groovy Then we will fix it